# Contact form validation javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, client-side

Yesterday I was following a tutorial for client-side validation using regular expressions. It worked well for the most part. I cannot figure out what I changed for this to stop working.

Basically, I don't think the form should be submitting at all, even if it passes validation. When I click submit and all fields are empty, they should all show the error message, but only the name field does. With error messages displayed, the form will still submit

HTML

```
  <form>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="name"       placeholder="Enter your name.." onkeyup='validateName()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ex: 1231231234" onkeyup='validatePhone()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onkeyup='validateEmail()'>
            <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
          </div>   

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for='contactMessage'>Your Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id='contact-message'  name='message'  placeholder="Enter a brief message" onkeyup='validateMessage()'></textarea>
            <span class='error-message' id='message-error'></span>
          </div>

        <button onclick='validateForm()' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
      </form>
```

JS

```
function validateName() {

  var name = document.getElementById('contact-name').value;

  if(name.length == 0) {

    producePrompt('Name is required', 'name-error' , 'red')
    return false;

  }

  if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/)) {

    producePrompt('First and last name, please.','name-error', 'red');
    return false;

  }

  producePrompt('Valid', 'name-error', 'green');
  return true;

}

function validatePhone() {

  var phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone').value;

    if(phone.length == 0) {
      producePrompt('Phone number is required.', 'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;
    }

    if(phone.length != 10) {
      producePrompt('Include area code.', 'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;
    }

    if(!phone.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/)) {
      producePrompt('Only digits, please.' ,'phone-error', 'red');
      return false;
    }

    producePrompt('Valid', 'phone-error', 'green');
    return true;

}

function validateEmail () {

  var email = document.getElementById('contact-email').value;

  if(email.length == 0) {

    producePrompt('Email Invalid','email-error', 'red');
    return false;

  }

  if(!email.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-[0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/)) {

    producePrompt('Email Invalid', 'email-error', 'red');
    return false;

  }

  producePrompt('Valid', 'email-error', 'green');
  return true;

}

function validateMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById('contact-message').value;
  var required = 30;
  var left = required - message.length;

  if (left > 0) {
    producePrompt(left + ' more characters required','message-error','red');
    return false;
  }

  producePrompt('Valid', 'message-error', 'green');
  return true;

}

function validateForm() {
  if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail() || !validateMessage()) {
    jsShow('submit-error');
    producePrompt('Please fix errors to submit.', 'submit-error', 'red');
    setTimeout(function(){jsHide('submit-error');}, 2000);
  }
  else {

  }
}

function jsShow(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

function jsHide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}




function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {

  document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;


}
```

I understand this isn't set up to actually send anything to PHP. I believe the javascript code should work find as there was nothing changed, but the HTML has.

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more descriptive about where your error is occurring? Have you tried opening the debugger and looked for any errors returned by the debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Nothing in debugger showing

Basically the form is submitting no matter what. Even if the javascript validation pops up for a second saying I can't leave a field blank or what ever.

Comment: You should use try...catch in the validation functions so that system errors will also be caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `return` to the click event:

```
<button onclick='return validateForm()' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Then, if fails, function should return `false`:

```
function validateForm() {
    if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail() || !validateMessage()) {
        jsShow('submit-error');
        producePrompt('Please fix errors to submit.', 'submit-error', 'red');
        setTimeout(function(){jsHide('submit-error');}, 2000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjkj7/)

Comment: thanks a bunch. was stressing over this for a while. now I just have to figure out how to include this client validation with ajax to PHP. Do you think my validation is compatible with an ajax approach to send emails through php?

Comment: Well, if you need ajax validation you can't use this method becouse is syncronous (and you need async). You should validate on JS, do your validation ajax requests, and if them success, then submit your form throught javascript (POST it).